# Visual Studio missing msvcr120d.dll and msvcp120d.dll error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 I cant run my exe on another computers because of missing missing msvcr120d.dll and msvcp120d.dll.

I already downloaded vcredist from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

I tried MT (Multi-threaded) but same error. :(
Please help I tried everything.

Comment: The solution is to compile a release configuration.

Comment: For programming related questions there is [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)